# PS4 WS-37397-9 Error Code.

Tags: technical-issues, ps4

I'm having this error and it's driving me insane. Do you guys have any ideas? I read [This](https://support.us.playstation.com/scea_searchresults?lang=en_US&selStr=ws-37397-9) but i'm not sure if Rebuild Database will erase all the data from my PS4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Rebuilding your database will not have any negative effects on your PS4's data**

This is actually quite a common fix for many issues. I've seen it recommended many times especially regarding slow loading messages, trophy syncing, and the friends list (although I haven't had to use it myself). Basically, you could just think of it as a refragmenting of sorts. I'm assuming it would be an especially good fix for you seeing as that link you posted is on a Sony support site.

I've re-posted the steps from your link, for quick reference to anyone viewing this question.

- Step 1: ​Turn off the PlayStation 4 by pressing the power button on the front panel. The power indicator will blink for a few moments before turning off.
- Step 2: ​Once the PlayStation 4 is off, press and hold the power button. Release it after you've heard two beeps: one when you initially press, and another 7 seconds later.
- Step 3: ​Connect the DualShock 4 controller with the provided USB cable and press the PS button on the controller.
- Step 4: From the list of options select Rebuild Database and press “X”. Once the process is complete the PS4 will restart.​
- Step 5: Run the Internet connection test at [Settings] > [Network] > [Test Internet Connection] and make sure you can connect to the network.​

And below are the steps to rebuild the database from [this site:](http://www.bidnessetc.com/55345-heres-how-to-rebuild-database-on-your-playstation-4/)

1. Turn off your PS4 by either holding down the power button or by holding down the PS button on your DualShock 4 controller and choose to shut down.
2. Once the console is completely powered off, turn on the console by holding down the power button until you hear the second beep. At this point, you can let go. There will be a “Safe Mode” menu on your screen now.
3. Pick up your DualShock 4 controller and connect it to your PS4 with a USB cable and press the PS button to turn it on.
4. Highlight the “Rebuild Database” and select it. Confirm the action after a message pops-up asking to continue.